# window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, $url, $message) issues

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor

I have pinned my errors down to the `callFunction($funcNum, $url, $message)` . What seems to be happening is that CKEditor calls my script that processes the image upload, it does everything it is supposed to and returns the required javascript

```
// echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, $url, $message);</script>"
```

However in the browser I get the following.

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I have a class that records what is going on in my upload script, this is what  I am finding that everything is sent correctly and my code is working correctly this is in my file that records info

```
Get contains Array
(
    [CKEditor] => tutorialStepDataField
    [CKEditorFuncNum] => 1
    [langCode] => en
)
,
FILES contains Array
(
    [upload] => Array
    (
        [name] => are you for serious.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpHwDy1E
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 11935
    )
)
```

I'm trying to process the image upload. The image name is `tutorial_imgs/1432888718.jpg`, the returnStr is :

> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 1, https://res.cloudinary.com/enterfan-com/image/upload/v1432888718/tutorial_imgs/1432888718.jpg, Upload was successful);,

It certainly appears everything is working, and in fact the image is processed and uploaded to my cloudinary account. I also have no Errors in any of my server error files that I can find.

When I click the "Send to Server" button, it sends it and I return the script above, however Nothing happens, the dialog does nothing and the browse button is gone and nothing is replaced there. 
I get the Syntax error in the console though, which makes no sense.

When I look at the debugger info for the syntax error I see the following

> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 0, empty, You must choose an image to upload);

Here is the code in my upload script.

```
    `$funcNum = 0;
    $url = 'empty';
    $returnStr = '<script type="text/javascript">';
   $returnStr .= 'window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( ';

if ( !empty( $_FILES[ 'upload' ][ 'name' ] ) )
{

  Misc_FileWriter::writeToFile(FILEWRITER_FILE, 'trying to process the image upload. '.  $_FILES[ 'upload' ][ 'name' ] );
  $tutorialImageUploader = new Upload_TutorialImageUploader( $_FILES );
  $tutorialImageUploader->uploadImage();
  $url = $tutorialImageUploader->getUploadedImageSecureUrl();

  $message = 'Upload was successful';
  $funcNum = $_GET[ 'CKEditorFuncNum' ];

}
else
{
  $message = 'You must choose an image to upload';
  Misc_FileWriter::writeToFile(FILEWRITER_FILE,' somehow !empty( $_FILES[ upload ][ name ] was magically  empty');
}


 $returnStr .= $funcNum . ', ' . $url . ', ' . $message . ');</script>';

 Misc_FileWriter::writeToFile(FILEWRITER_FILE, 'the returnStr is ' . $returnStr);
// echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, $url, $message);</script>";
echo $returnStr;`
```

This doesn't make sense to me. None of my searches on Stack or Google turn anything useful up. Has anyone had issues similar to this? Anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Thanks for any advice. I love the CKEditor, but some of the documentation makes me want to punch my monitor. LOLZ

Comment: Ok I finally figured it out. Here is what the problem was. The documentation shows 

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>"

I didn't have single quotes around URL and Message. The docs do not mentin why that is important. I rewrote the code to. 
$returnStr = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$returnStr .= 'window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( ';
$returnStr .= $funcNum . ", '" . $url . "', '" . $message . "' );</script>";

Now it works. What a pain figuring that out.

Comment: It has nothing to do with CKEditor. String variables should be passed in single quotes. That's obvious.